# ERROR: permission denied for function geography_eq

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Recently I've swapped Docker container for my PostgreSQL 11 database from `postgres` to `postgis/postgis:11-2.5-alpine`, added column `geolocation public.geography(Point,4326)` to `public.user` table and that's it.

Nothing from PostGIS is being used so far.

In some point of my application, I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for function geography_eq
CONTEXT:  SQL function "user_private_message_peers" statement 1
STATEMENT:  select to_json((__local_0__."id")) as "id", to_json((with __local_1__ as (select to_json((json_build_object('id'::text, (__local_2__."id"), 'nickname'::text, (__local_2__."nickname")))) as "@nodes"
db_1    |   from "public"."user_private_message_peers"(__local_0__) as __local_2__
db_1    |   
db_1    |   where (TRUE) and (TRUE)
db_1    |   
db_1    |   
db_1    |   ), __local_3__ as (select json_agg(to_json(__local_1__)) as data from __local_1__) select json_build_object('data'::text, coalesce((select __local_3__.data from __local_3__), '[]'::json)) )) as "@privateMessagePeers"
db_1    |   from "public"."current_user"() as __local_0__
db_1    |   
db_1    |   where (not (__local_0__ is null)) and (TRUE) and (TRUE)
```

A function `user_private_message_peers` has not changed after migrating to PostGIS:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.user_private_message_peers("user" public."user") RETURNS SETOF public."user"
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT
    AS $$
        SELECT
          distinct u.*
        FROM
          "user" AS u
        INNER JOIN
          "privateMessage" pm ON (
            pm."recipientId" = u.id OR pm."senderId" = u.id
          )
        WHERE (
          u.id != "user".id
        ) AND ((
          pm."senderId" = 1 AND pm."recipientId" != 1
        ) OR (
          pm."senderId" != 1 AND pm."recipientId" = 1
        ));
      $$
```

No indexes on `public.user.geolocation` column are presented.

```sql
SELECT
    tablename,
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'user'
ORDER BY
    tablename,
    indexname;
```

| tablename | indexname | indexdef |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user | user_nickname_key | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_nickname_key ON public."user" USING btree (nickname) |
| user | user_pkey | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_pkey ON public."user" USING btree (id) |

Is there some implicit usage of `geography_eq` function somewhere?

Update:

Default privileges are:

```
\ddp
Default access privileges
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+--------------------
Owner             | postgres
Schema            | 
Type              | function
Access privileges | postgres=X/postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the function that implements the equality operator for the `geography` type has broken permissions. Somehow, your PostGIS installation got messed up.

The best fix would be to drop and recreate the `postgis` extension.

Check with `psql` if you have any default privileges defined: `\ddp`

Comment: A dump of database schema displays series of `REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_eq(public.geography, public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;` statements for all entities from PostGIS. Is it a deviation from defaults?

Comment: Yes, that is a deviation.

Comment: Ok, will figure it out. But I still don't understand, why this violation happens in a place, where PostGIS functions are not used? Btw., they are not used at all in my database…

Comment: It is very hard to figure out after the fact what caused a problem. If you retained your PostgreSQL log files, and you have `log_statement = 'ddl'`, you could dig there.

Comment: I've noticed, that PostgreSQL database revokes all privileges on all entities of extension, being created. Is it a default behaviour? Not found about it in official documentation.

Comment: No, that is not the default behavior. Check `\ddp` like I said. Are you using PostgreSQL or some hacked up fork of it?