# PostgreSQL revokes all privileges on all entities of extension, being created

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgis

This question follows up my another question [ERROR: permission denied for function geography_eq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027090/error-permission-denied-for-function-geography-eq/66028418?noredirect=1#comment116742759_66028418)

What PostgreSQL should do by default with permissions on entities of extension, being created?

Here is a case.

Initially my database cluster was managed by PostgreSQL 11 installation in Docker container, created from `postgres-11` image.

I needed to store GPS coordinates., so, I have changed Docker container from `postgres` to `postgis/postgis:11-2.5-alpine`.

Added extension:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Created a dump and noticed, that privileges on all functions from PostGIS are revoked for all roles:

```sql
--
-- Name: FUNCTION geog_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geog_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_compress(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_compress(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_consistent(internal, public.geography, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_consistent(internal, public.geography, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_decompress(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_decompress(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_distance(internal, public.geography, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_distance(internal, public.geography, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_penalty(internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_penalty(internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_picksplit(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_picksplit(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_same(public.box2d, public.box2d, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_same(public.box2d, public.box2d, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gist_union(bytea, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gist_union(bytea, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_gt(public.geography, public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_gt(public.geography, public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_le(public.geography, public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_le(public.geography, public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_lt(public.geography, public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_lt(public.geography, public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geography_overlaps(public.geography, public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geography_overlaps(public.geography, public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geom2d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geom2d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geom3d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geom3d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geom4d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geom4d_brin_inclusion_add_value(internal, internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(bytea); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(bytea) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(path); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(path) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(point); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(point) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(polygon); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(polygon) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(text); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(text) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(public.box2d); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(public.box2d) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(public.box3d); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(public.box3d) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry(public.geometry, integer, boolean); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry(public.geometry, integer, boolean) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_above(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_above(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_below(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_below(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_cmp(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_cmp(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_contained_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_contained_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_contained_by_raster(public.geometry, public.raster); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_contained_by_raster(public.geometry, public.raster) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_contains(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_contains(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_contains_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_contains_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_distance_box(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_distance_box(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_distance_centroid(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_distance_centroid(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_distance_centroid_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_distance_centroid_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_distance_cpa(public.geometry, public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_distance_cpa(public.geometry, public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_eq(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_eq(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_ge(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_ge(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_compress_2d(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_compress_2d(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_compress_nd(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_compress_nd(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_consistent_2d(internal, public.geometry, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_consistent_2d(internal, public.geometry, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_consistent_nd(internal, public.geometry, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_consistent_nd(internal, public.geometry, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_decompress_2d(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_decompress_2d(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_decompress_nd(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_decompress_nd(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_distance_2d(internal, public.geometry, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_distance_2d(internal, public.geometry, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_distance_nd(internal, public.geometry, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_distance_nd(internal, public.geometry, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_penalty_2d(internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_penalty_2d(internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_penalty_nd(internal, internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_penalty_nd(internal, internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_picksplit_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_picksplit_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_picksplit_nd(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_picksplit_nd(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_same_2d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_same_2d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_same_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_same_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_union_2d(bytea, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_union_2d(bytea, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gist_union_nd(bytea, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gist_union_nd(bytea, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_gt(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_gt(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_hash(public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_hash(public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_le(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_le(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_left(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_left(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_lt(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_lt(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overabove(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overabove(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overbelow(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overbelow(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overlaps(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overlaps(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overlaps_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overlaps_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overlaps_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overlaps_nd(public.geometry, public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overleft(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overleft(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_overright(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_overright(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_raster_contain(public.geometry, public.raster); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_raster_contain(public.geometry, public.raster) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_raster_overlap(public.geometry, public.raster); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_raster_overlap(public.geometry, public.raster) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_right(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_right(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_same(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_same(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_same_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_same_3d(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_choose_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_choose_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_choose_3d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_choose_3d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_compress_2d(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_compress_2d(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_compress_3d(internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_compress_3d(internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_config_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_config_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_config_3d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_config_3d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_inner_consistent_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_inner_consistent_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_inner_consistent_3d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_inner_consistent_3d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_leaf_consistent_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_leaf_consistent_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_leaf_consistent_3d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_leaf_consistent_3d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_picksplit_2d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_picksplit_2d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_spgist_picksplit_3d(internal, internal); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_spgist_picksplit_3d(internal, internal) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometry_within(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometry_within(geom1 public.geometry, geom2 public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometrytype(public.geography); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometrytype(public.geography) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geometrytype(public.geometry); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geometrytype(public.geometry) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geomfromewkb(bytea); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geomfromewkb(bytea) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION geomfromewkt(text); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.geomfromewkt(text) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION get_proj4_from_srid(integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.get_proj4_from_srid(integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION gettransactionid(); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.gettransactionid() FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION graphql_subscription(); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.graphql_subscription() FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION gserialized_gist_joinsel_2d(internal, oid, internal, smallint); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.gserialized_gist_joinsel_2d(internal, oid, internal, smallint) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION gserialized_gist_joinsel_nd(internal, oid, internal, smallint); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.gserialized_gist_joinsel_nd(internal, oid, internal, smallint) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION gserialized_gist_sel_2d(internal, oid, internal, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.gserialized_gist_sel_2d(internal, oid, internal, integer) FROM PUBLIC;


--
-- Name: FUNCTION gserialized_gist_sel_nd(internal, oid, internal, integer); Type: ACL; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.gserialized_gist_sel_nd(internal, oid, internal, integer) FROM PUBLIC;
```

Is it a default behaviour or something goes wrong?

I found nothing relevant in official documentation about this topic.

When I'm creating an extension, how PostgreSQL 11 should behave with entities of this extension?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility for that in standard PostgreSQL is that the *default privileges* for functions have been changed.

In particular, if the extension is create by user `postgres`, someone must have issued this at an earlier point:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres
   REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM PUBLIC;
```

You can see that with `\ddp` in `psql`, but also with a metadata query:

```
\ddp

             Default access privileges
  Owner   | Schema |   Type   |  Access privileges  
----------+--------+----------+---------------------
 postgres |        | function | postgres=X/postgres
(1 row)

SELECT defaclrole::regrole AS user,
       defaclnamespace::regnamespace AS schema,
       defaclobjtype,
       defaclacl
FROM pg_default_acl;

   user   | schema | defaclobjtype |       defaclacl       
----------+--------+---------------+-----------------------
 postgres | -      | f             | {postgres=X/postgres}
(1 row)
```

To undo that change, run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres
   GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO PUBLIC;
```